An optional step that does limit the claim
A method, comprising:
a. identifying at least one of a first score and a second score of a first user;
b. optionally, in response to identifying the first score, identifying a third score;
c. optionally, in response to identifying the second score, identifying a fourth score;
d. determining an output based on the first score, the second score, the third score, and the fourth score;
e. in response to determining the output, sending the output to the first user; and
f. in response to determining the output wherein both the third score and the fourth score are not identified, sending the values of the first score and the second score to the first user,
wherein the method uses zero in place of scores that are not identified

Because of step (f), steps (b) and (c), even though optional, do in fact LIMIT this claim. Step (f) is performed if and only if both steps (b) and (c) are omitted.
Question:

Do you agree that this claim may be valid, of course assuming everything else holds up?
Do you agree that steps (b) and (c) both limit the claim due to step (f)?
Actually, both steps (b) and (c) are also limiting due to step (d), because if they are not identified, they will affect the output differently than if they are identified. If they are not identified, then a zero is used in their place, which of course will have a different effect on an algorithm that uses it as input. Do you agree, that the optional steps of (b) and (c) are limiting due to step (d)?


Sometimes it's helpful to boil these kinds of issues down to their essence.
Claim 1: A method, comprising, in order:

a. starting a timer
b. optionally snapping one's fingers
c. clapping only if one didn't snap one's fingers since starting the timer
d. stopping said timer

Claim 2: A method, comprising, in order:

a. starting a timer
b. clapping only if one didn't snap one's fingers since starting the timer
c. stopping said timer

Now what infringes what?
Nothing: 1 not infringed because we didn't clap. 2 not infringed for same reason.
Snap only: 1 infringed. 2 infringed because it's comprising and one can still snap.
Clap only: 1 infringed. 2 infringed.
Snap then clap: 1 not infringed. 2 not infringed.
Clap then snap: 1 infringed because comprising and one can have an additional clap before the optional snap (or possibly indefinite). 2 infringed.
As you can see, it makes no difference to infringement (or anticipation) that there is an optional method step.

I understand what you mean now. I think the difference is that you can reference "snap one's fingers" at anytime without having to introduce it, and it won't be confusing to the reader/examiner. In my example, without explicitly writing down the optional step, it would be confusing for the reader/examiner when they encounter the hitherto undefined terms of "third score" and "fourth score".

I think we assumed that the spec told us what identifying and score and user mean.
